# How do i create a form in Ionic 3 using *ngFor to loop through a list of inputs?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic2, ionic3

form.html

```
<form #form='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form.value)" novalidate>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let parameter of parameters">
    <ion-label color="primary" floating>{{parameter.Description}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input name="parameter.Identifier" ([ngModel])="parameter.value"  
               type="parameter.parameterType" 
               max="parameter.maxLength"
               min="parameter.minLength">
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button type="submit" block>Aceptar</button>
</form>
```

form.ts

```
submitForm(form){
  console.log("form", form);
}
```

I'm building a transaction processing application and building forms one by one isn't a realistic option since I would have to build hundreds and they are constantly changing. I developed an angular 4 application that worked pretty well with forms generated this way. However I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Ionic 3. The submitForm(form) method in typescript only prints form{} in the console. I'm unable to obtain the input data from the the generated forms.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Did you look at using Reactive forms instead of Template driver form for this? Reactive forms seems to be a better approach for this.

Comment: Under the cover Ionic is just Angular, if your form worked in a Angular 4 applicaton it should work here. If you're already binding the input `[(ngModel)]` to `parameter.value` why not access your form data in your parameters array when you submit?

Comment: Thanks Hisham. I somehow missed reactive forms when I overviewed the documentation. And event though reactive forms wasn't the solution I was looking for I actually stumbled upon dynamic forms while reading about reactive forms.

Comment: By the way Gabriel, what you suggested Is a solution but given the complexity and extent of the forms I thought doing it that way would be too complicated. However I appreciate the help.